# Insert macros around changes between git commits

Tags: git

I need to surround git changes between commits with #ifdef macros. This will help me to enable/disable my changes using macros. The idea is to switch quickly between two different source implementations.

Is there a tool to perform this ? If not what is the best approach to achieve the above?

Comment: Can you clarify by giving an example of the kind of change you want to occur? My first impression is that `git` may not be the tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically affect all your changes while committing by creating pre-commit hook. To do it, create an executable *pre-commit* file in  *.git/hooks/* directory:

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit
```

You can use Bash, Python, Perl, Ruby within it - any executable script would be fine. Examine already present in *.git/hooks* *pre-commit.sample* - it will give you some useful info how to approach writing your script.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Just edited it a little bit. It seems to me that this is the problem which is addressed here.